# How to display 3D and 2D plots on top of each other?

Tags: matlab, plot, overlay

Namely, a spectrogram, and another plot.

```
N = 1000000;
win = 3125;                                
no = floor(win/2);                        
nfft = floor(log2(N));
fs = 31250;                          
data = pm_data.ch4(1:N);
Fr = 20:10:5000;
t = 1/fs:1/fs:N/fs;
spectrogram(data,hann(win),no,Fr,fs,'yaxis');
colorbar;
set(gca,'Yscale','log')
plot(t,ai_data.ch1(1:N))
```

I tried putting "hold on" before spectrogram, but it didn't work :\

Comment: Possibly use [`plot3`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot3.html), where one of the axes is a constant. Hard to say without code that doesn't require toolboxes.

Comment: Please initialize all variables when posting code examples. If the content does not matter, use `rand` or similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For two plots to be combined, they must have the same axes. So, the 2D curve you'd be plotting with `plot` should be put in 3D space by `plot3`, as excaza suggested. Here is a simple example: a parabola on a paraboloid. I use zeros for y-coordinate in `plot3`, and a thick line with contrasting color to set it aside from the surface.

```
x = -1:0.1:1;
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x, x);
surf(X, Y, X.^2-Y.^2)
hold on 
plot3(x, zeros(size(x)), x.^2, 'k', 'linewidth', 5)
hold off
```

[image: paraboloid]

Comment: great! thanks :) Is there a way to do the same and have different axes for each? Like this: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plotyy.html